# Prove if a | b, then a | bc for all integers c ,true

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Please prove that ) if a | b, then a | bc for all integers c;

my solution: b= a x j
             c= a x d
and I don't know what do I have to do next or how can I have a good proof.

Comment: If $b = aj$ then $bc = ajc$.  Does $a | ajc$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\mid b$ then $b=ak$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. We want to show that $a\mid bc$, i.e. we need to show that there exists some integer $m$ where $bc=am$.

$$bc=(ak)c=a(kc)$$
so we have found an $m$ that works, namely $m=kc$ so $a\mid bc$.